# role of xsl in dynamically generating HTML pages from relational database

Tags: xslt

can anybody explain the role that XSL can play when dynamically generating HTML pages from a relational database?

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, XSL can act as a presentation layer to adapt/customize the naked data retrieved by a data access layer from a database.
This layering can be good because:

- data issues (checks on values,
  performances, resource pooling...)
  are quite different from presentation
  issues (HTML layout, browser
  compatibilities, ...)
- presentation requirements are volatile, and you don't want to mess
  with data
- you may want to support several output formats (e.g. HTML, LaTeX, WML
  if it still exists, CSV values...),
  or simply want to keep that
  possibility open

XSL is particularly well-suited for dealing with structured data like those retrieved from a database, and adding an output format may just mean copying and pasting an existing XSL into another one with minor tweaks. 
On the other side, XSL can rapidly become a nightmare if you have to consider lots of odd cases.

Without further information (are you talking of server-side apps or desktop apps? Which programming language/platform?) I can't give more specific advice.